# Creating FS wallets on solana using JSON RPC

Tags: filesystems, json-rpc, solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli

I'm new to Solana and trying to create FS wallets using JSON RPC API. I read about `solana CLI` interface and can generate new FS wallets using `solana-keygen new <path-to-wallet.json-file>`. But now I'm trying to do the same using JSON RPC. I've installed python [client](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/) for the purpose but couldn't find how to do that using that client. I'm connected to `devnet` cluster and can use CLI smoothly but wants to do the same using JSON RPC. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A file system wallet is just a JSON-encoded array of 64 bytes, i.e.

```
[144,14,239,36,55,74,88,13,156,116,241,90,128,236,78,228,107,31,163,192,87,111,115,179,102,156,95,175,141,214,242,59,100,51,187,180,77,254,194,99,11,126,9,57,115,190,156,251,141,82,79,159,150,37,216,246,193,172,71,65,153,212,158,85]
```

If you want to create one in Python, you can do:

```py
import json
from solana.keypair import Keypair

wallet = Keypair()
wallet_bytes = list(wallet.secret_key)
output_file = open('fs.json', 'w')
json.dump(wallet_bytes, output_file)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jon C. Can you please tell me how can I do with secret key from the user?

Comment: That's a different solution -- if you want the user to sign something, you'll typically do that through a wallet, which signs the transaction created by your frontend.  The main module to use is https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/